# Android - Invalid Double "#,##"

Tags: java, android

A user of my app is having a error and the app is crashing

I've looked at the report and it's stating

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "1,36"

I have reproduced the data inputted on my app and I don't have the issue at all

I have even asked her to send me her database so i can import the exact data and it still worked okay for me

I'm confused as to where the double is getting formatted like that as I can't see anywhere in my code where it would get formatted with a ,

Any suggestions as to what's going on?

Comment: Is the user french ? Must be a locale issue

Comment: As you can see there is comma after number 1. And some where in your code you are parsing string to double.user might have input the data like 1,36

Comment: Invalid double: "1,36", -> It is valid double: "1.36"

Comment: Some locales use `,` as a decimal separator. Without seeing your code, it's impossible to say where your value get's formatted like that.

Comment: I have double checked the data inputted, no where is there a , inputted by user

So i'm assuming it's to do with this locales where if the user is in a different country the formatting gets done differently?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646746/numberformatexception-on-european-versions-of-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just have faced the same problem. I was converting float value to String. Yes, it must be a locale issue. As said in one of the comments, Some locales use , as a decimal separator.
Initially I was converting float like-

```
String.format("%.1f", value);
```

Then I changed the code to

```
String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.1f", value);
```

So, forcing the string to be converted with English local worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way is (do it above your parce):

```
if (str.contains(",")) {
    str.replace(",",".");
}
```

Comment: Hi @walkmn thanks for the suggestion, the only issue is that I would have to do this for every time a double is parsed, which would be a bit of a pain and it's more of a work around

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have encountered a locale problem. Different locales have `.` and `,` as fractional part separator. You can use [`java.text.NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) to work with the locale you want, e.g. `FRANCE` for comma and `US` for point:

```
// somewhere at Utils.java:

public static final NumberFormat DOUBLE_FORMAT = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);

// at call site:

double d = Utils.DOUBLE_FORMAT.parse("1,234").doubleValue();
```